# How to create extension for block & storing searched URL's using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, console, store, webrequest

for url blocking I got some code.  below code working for url blocking ,if new url is  searched (url not exixt in list/string) I need to store that new  url in  a new variable. How to write that code using Javascript, below code is for blocking.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( function(details) { 
// console.log(details)
return {cancel: true}; },{urls: 
["*://*.gettyimages.in/*",
"*://*.pixabay.com/*",
"*://*.xvideos.com/*","*://*.xnxx.com/*","*://*.xnxx2.com/*",
"*://*.xvideos3.com/*",
"*://*.123rf.com/*"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

Comment: Hi Hemanth! Can you please elaborate a little more what do you mean by blocking & storing searched urls?

Comment: I need to create web browser extension for url blocking & storing, so if url present in the list(list contains blocking url's) it will be blocked ,otherwise it will be stored in a new list